# getting street distances locally

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I need a few thousands of street distances between cities in germany. 
I know that there are a few web APIs where I get the distance thru a REST request, but I wonder if I can do that locally on my Linux PC. I saw the OSRM project and libosrm seems to do what I want.
Are there any other tools doing that?
What do I have to download and what do I have to install?
(I prefer to program in python)

Answer (score 2):

Set up a local instance of one of the [OSM-based routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), e.g. [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/) or [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/). Then just use their APIs. There should be python-bindings for the most popular routers available.

Comment: Is there a document how to set up OSRM and what OSM data to download?

Comment: Yes, see the [OSRM Wiki at GitHub](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki). There are also ready to use docker images available.

Comment: Ok, build done. Downloaded and prepared the data as in https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Running-OSRM and it works. Thx.

Comment: Sounds great :)